# Alternative to current_user

Tags: tokens, media

I have modified user-picture.tpl.php the follow way:

```
$employeeid = token_replace('[current-user:field_employeeid]');
?>
<?php if ($user_picture): ?>
<div class="user-picture">
    <?php print $user_picture; ?>
</div>
<?php elseif ($employeeid): ?>
<div class="user-picture">
    <img src="../../sites/default/files/pictures/<?=$employeeid?>.jpg"/>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

by adding a token_replace to manage the current-user avatar for a company directory. I have left the original options in place because there is the possibility for non employees to be logged in.

THE PROBLEM:

The above code works, provided you are the current user, I need the employee avatar to show for everyone. I have tried replacing

```
curent-user:
```

for

```
user:
```

with no success. The whole reason for this is so that the employee avatar is automatically pulled from an IMCE managed folder and NOT left up to the employee to "get creative".

Any constructive thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

SOLUTION:

```
if (isset($account->field_employeeid['und'][0]['safe_value'])) : 
    $employeeid = $account->field_employeeid['und'][0]['safe_value']; ?>
    <div class="user-picture">
        <img src="<?=base_path()?>sites/default/files/pictures/<?=$employeeid?>.jpg"/>
    </div>
<?  else: ?>
    <div class="user-picture">
        <?php print $user_picture; ?>
    </div>
<?  endif; ?>
```

Comment: are you trying to display the picture of a user on his or her "page" ?  if so, you need to grab the uid of that node and use it in your template instead of the uid of the current user.

Comment: I am attempting to show a picture which is managed by IMCE, on the user profile page, based on the the EMPLOYEEID which is being populate by LDAP into the user profile as a Field value.

Comment: well if you load the user's profile, you have that field value and can use it just as easily as the uid field or am I totally missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say remove the `if/else` and only leave the `else` code, as you never want to show `$user_picture`

```
$employeeid = token_replace('[current-user:field_employeeid]');
?>
<div class="user-picture">
    <img src="<?=base_path()?>sites/default/files/pictures/<?=$employeeid?>.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I want the ability to show BOTH. I have both drupal-only users and drupal-ldap users. The drupal users can have a custom avatar but the ldap created users must use their id pic that is maintain by HR via a folder in IMCE

Comment: so .. change your if condition to see if the file exists (best with [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)), if not use the $user_picture.

Comment: also change ../../ to [base_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7)